# Iterate python list object and invoke each object's method

Tags: python, list

I have simple class like this

```
class MyClass():
    def test(self):
      print "Calling Test"
```

Then i create a list:

```
lobj=[MyClass() for i in range (100)]
```

Now I want to iterate each object in `lobj` and invoke its medthod `test()`. 
I know i can use `for` loop. However, i wonder if there is any other way (just to avoid the for loop when the list is relatively large)? For example

```
lobj[:].test()
```

Comment: Do you want to capture the result of that `test` function?

Comment: Why does the size of the list matter for whether or not you use a `for` loop? Any thing that calls a method on each object is going to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *...I wonder if there is any other way (just to avoid the for loop when the list is relatively large)?*

**Yes**. You can use the built-in function [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and a lambda function. If you want to just call the method on each element, do:

```
map(lambda x:x.test(), lobj)
```

And if you want to store the results in a list:

```
v = map(lambda x:x.test(), lobj)
```

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is:

```
[i.test() for i in lobj]
```

This calls the method but then doesn't store the result anywhere so the list gets discarded after it is done calling the method for all the instances.

Comment: Thanks. I can be done in this way too.
I would like to up vote your answer but I don't have enough rep.